# Grand Central Dispatch and concurrent tasks

Tags: ios, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I need to perform three tasks that are independent one from each other, so I'd like to execute them concurrently. But I need them all to have finished to notify another object. AFAIK, *dispatch_apply* creates concurrent threads, but it iterates a collection or an array of objects and performs the same task a number of loops, and I want to perform a different task for each thread. Is it possible to do what I want by using GCD? If not, what should be the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `dispatch_group`. The [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) gives one example, and there is [more API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW19) that might also help you.

- Create a dispatch group using `dispatch_group_create`.
- Put each "task" in the group by enqueuing it using `dispatch_group_async`.

  (Or, manually tell GCD when each task starts and stops, using `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave`.)
- To run a block when all tasks in the group have completed, enqueue it using `dispatch_group_notify`.

  (Or, in the unlikely case that the design of your app allows you to wait synchronously, use `dispatch_group_wait` instead.)
- When you're done with the group, `dispatch_release` it.

Comment: Related to this... what if I'm dispatching the group from a method that should return a value, and I need to do it when 'dispatch_group_notify' reached?

Comment: If you're in a method that needs to return a value that depends on the tasks in the group, then `dispatch_group_wait` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Dispatch Groups are what you need. Look at the GCD functions. What you will do is create the group and a concurrent queue (or use thee standard ones). Associate the three operations (blocks) with the dispatch_group, then create a forth block, and have that block do a dispatch_group_wait (typing names by memory), then when that returns, it can post a 'success' message to some other object. Put the block with the wait into any concurrent queue.

I do exactly this in my app.

Answer (score 4):

I know you asked about GCD, but [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) is another possibility. For example:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3;

// create my completion operation (which will be added to the queue later, once
// the dependencies with all of the other operations has been established)

NSBlockOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"All done");
}];

// let's add our three operations

NSBlockOperation *operation;

operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"starting task 1");
    sleep(5);
    NSLog(@"stopping task 1");
}];

[completionOperation addDependency:operation];
[queue addOperation:operation];

operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"starting task 2");
    sleep(4);
    NSLog(@"stopping task 2");
}];

[completionOperation addDependency:operation];
[queue addOperation:operation];

operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"starting task 3");
    sleep(6);
    NSLog(@"stopping task 3");
}];

[completionOperation addDependency:operation];
[queue addOperation:operation];

// now let's add the completion operation (which has been configured as dependent
// upon the other operations

[queue addOperation:completionOperation];
```

There are tons of different ways of tackling this problem, but `NSOperationQueue` is another option. The [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1) discusses all of the options.